# copy (partial) redis data from one server to another

Tags: redis

I am searching for a solution to copy a specific db from one redis server to another.
The two servers are not located in the same site, or have any sort of connection between them- so the data must be passed via some dump file.

I don't want to use `bgsave` command and move the dump.rdb file to the target server, as this will transfer ALL redis db's and will overwrite existing data on the target. (I want just a specific db)

what other solutions are available?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this process works for you:

1. Dump to RDB file
2. Load RDB on a fresh instance
3. Delete undesired DBs and dump again
4. Use `DEBUG RELOAD NOSAVE NOFLUSH MERGE` (not documented command) to load the RDB file from step 3

[See here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/debug.c#L369) for more info on step 4.

As always, test the process before running in production

Answer (score 0):

I guess Redis is not supposed to synchronize between locations, to do the synchronation you are better off putting the crutial data in traditional database like postgresql or MariaDB, who have a builtin function to synchronize and backup data.